# Hide all text on y axis dc.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, dc.js

I am creating a DC.JS based dashboard, but would like to figure out how to hide all of the text on the y axis of the bar chart as well as style the text on the x axis.

Thanks

[image: Fig 1]

Answer (score 12):

You should decrease ticks to zero:  `yourChart.yAxis().ticks(0);`

Note that this does not return a reference to your chart, so you cannot chain this method.  You must put it on a separate line.  Like this:

```
var yourChart = dc.barChart('#your-chart').width(1024).height(50);
yourChart.yAxis().ticks(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should decrease ticks for axis `yourChart.yAxis().ticks(0);`

Comment: Can you explain why this is the solution?

Comment: Hi Pronix, I have tried this before, but it resulted in none of the graphs being displayed. I have attempted to resolve the issue using CSS, #dc-bar-chart .axis.y
    {
    opacity: 0.0;
            
    } But this creates a gap between the axis label and the where the bars start..

Comment: for me it is working correct - disappear all text for y axis. it is standart d3.js options - if not working , require set `debugger;` to d3.js for understand what missed.

Comment: @TomWhitaker note the answer above, I almost downvoted until I read the part that said 'you cannot chain this method as it doesn't return a reference'. This worked for me after putting it on an entirely new line.