# Removing X-Labels of barChart in DC.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a bar chart that created in [dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js) and hosted in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBehtemam/9MFwQ/). i want to remove x labels of this chart . after searching i find [this SF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442233/hide-all-text-on-y-axis-dc-js-bar-chart) question. but even i set

```
 .xAxis().ticks(0)
```

it doesn't work and i can see the label.so how can i remove the `xAxis` labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.tickValues()` function instead, passing an empty array:

```
.xAxis().tickValues([]);
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9MFwQ/1/).